# django loaddata issue with new datetime field in postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, loaddata, dumpdata

i recently converted a project's database from sqlite to postgres, because of timezone issues.  The conversion works fine in my local dev environment.  However, in my production environment on webfaction, when I try to use loaddata to populate the db from my json file, I get the following error message:

```
Problem installing fixture 'smartcarpools.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mb52089/webapps/smartcarpools_prod/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 169, in handle
    for obj in objects:
  File "/home/mb52089/webapps/smartcarpools_prod/lib/python2.7/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 35, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream), **options):
  File "/home/mb52089/webapps/smartcarpools_prod/lib/python2.7/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 128, in Deserializer
    data[field.name] = field.to_python(field_value)
  File "/home/mb52089/webapps/smartcarpools_prod/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])
ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']
```

I noticed that webfaction uses postgres 8.3 while my local dev environment uses 9.1.

Any help for a beginner is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything mentioning PostgreSQL in your error. It is complaining about not having a valid date/time. Have you checked to make sure smarcarpools.json has all its date-times in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" format?

Oh - and PostgreSQL 8.3 was released back in 2008. You will want to:

1. See if webfaction (a hosting company?) offer something more current
2. Read the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release.html) for versions 8.4, 9.0, 9.1 so you have some idea of what is different. Bear in mind that you can't simply dump a 9.1 database and load it into 8.3, although you should be able to go the other direction.

If you can't get an up-to-date version on your host, grab a copy of 8.3 for your platform - if you're on a unix system then compiling from source is simple enough.

Comment: I migrated to a new server at webfaction, with pg 9.1 on it.  Still the same error message about datetimes. Strange that I can loaddata on my dev setup with pg 9.1 with no issue.  Same dumpdata json.  I'm stumped

Comment: It's not a PostgreSQL error. Try to get the "bad" value printed out - the problem is either in the data or Python's testing of it.  Good news with PG9.1 - lots of improvements in the past few versions.

Comment: I manually edited the offending date data and it works now.  Still confused why I didn't have to do that for my local install of PG9.1 but did have to do it for webfaction, but oh well.

Comment: If you show *what* changes you made maybe someone could tell you. Are you certain you have all the same versions of all the same modules on each system?

Comment: I'm all set now. Everything is working OK.  Thanks for the help!